# Visual SVN - Cant Access the Server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have setup a `Visual SVN Server` on my PC, but I cant even access it on this machine with an IP address (neither of local network, nor of Live external IP). The only way its working is via `http://localhost`

So is there a way to make it work on the network? or does it need an external web server?

Thanks.

Comment: When you open VisualSVN Server Manager, what does it say on the right hand panel in the 'Status' section?

Answer (score 1):

You should check what port the SVN server is running on (mine is 8443), and then make sure that your firewall (most likely the windows built-in firewall) allows incoming connections on this port.

Comment: I did turnoff the windows firewall, and its running on 80